# probability of repeated combinations

Tags: probability-theory

I'm considering combinations of 3 coin flips. we get 8 combinations.

Probability 1 of 8 combinations = 1/8 = 0.125.

It is expected that 1 combination will fall 3 times in a row = 0,125 * 0,125 * 0,125 = 0,0019.

Am I right ?

Calculator "The number of tests to get a certain number of events", believed that for the appearance of this series, the number of times necessary is: minimum 525, maximum 1052 test. Is the standard deviation included?

As far as I understand, the test consists of 3 flips, the result should be multiplied by 3 to get the number of single flips?

The probability A of the combination is 1/8 = 0.125.
The probability B of the combination is 1/8 = 0.125.
The probability of combinations A, B in any sequence (AAA; BBB; ABA ...) = (0,125 * 2) = 0,25 ^ 3 = 0,015?

Comment: If by "combination" you mean a fixed sequence of $3$ outcomes, then yes, the probability is $1/8$ and the probability that it occurs $3$ times in a row is $1/8^3-1/512$  I don't understand the paragraph starting "Calculator" at all.  What is the "Calculator?"  What exactly are you trying to calculate?

Comment: "Calculator?"=computation program